# INSERT values into table using cursor.execute

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing some code that will pull data from an API and insert the records into a table for me.

I'm unsure how to go about formatting my insert statement. I want to insert values where there is no existing match in the table (based on date), and I don't want to insert values where the column opponents = my school's team.

```
import datetime
import requests
import cx_Oracle
import os
from pytz import timezone

currentYear = 2020

con = Some_datawarehouse
cursor = con.cursor()

json_obj = requests.get('https://api.collegefootballdata.com/games?year='+str(currentYear)+'&seasonType=regular&team=myteam')\
    .json()

for item in json_obj:
    EVENTDATE = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').date()
    EVENTTIME = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(item['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').replace(tzinfo=timezone('EST')).time())
    FINAL_SCORE = item.get("home_points", None)
    OPPONENT = item.get("away_team", None)
    OPPONENT_FINAL_SCORE = item.get("away_points", None)
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable(EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME,FINAL_SCORE,OPPONENT,OPPONENT_FINAL_SCORE) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)
                        WHERE OPPONENT <> 'my team'
                        AND EVENTDATE NOT EXISTS (SELECT EVENTDATE FROM mytable);''',
                   [EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME,FINAL_SCORE,OPPONENT,OPPONENT_FINAL_SCORE])
con.commit()
con.close
```

This may be more of an ORACLE SQL rather than python question, but I'm not sure if cursor.execute can accept MERGE statements. I also recognize that the WHERE statement will not work here, but this is more of an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: cx_Oracle's `execute()` accepts Oracle SQL MERGE statements: you probably already tested it by now.

Comment: A side comment about data loading: if you have multiple records then make sure you are using `executemany()`.  See [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Answer (score 0):

change the sql query to this :

```
INSERT INTO mytable(EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME,FINAL_SCORE,OPPONENT,OPPONENT_FINAL_SCORE) 
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)) vt(EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME,FINAL_SCORE,OPPONENT,OPPONENT_FINAL_SCORE)
WHERE vt.OPPONENT <> 'my team'
AND vt.EVENTDATE NOT IN (SELECT EVENTDATE FROM mytable);
```